# ArcGIS giving measured distances and the scalebar incorrectly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, coordinate-system, distance, scale

I am currently using ArcGIS 10.1 and am struggling to be able to measure distance or set a scale bar correctly. Its currently giving me absurd results orders of magnitudes to small (0.5m etc). All my layers are in OSGB36 Transverse Mercator (BNG) (at least thats what Arc is telling me). I am struggling to figure our what is causing the issue although I'm thinking it must be something to do with the layers and their coordinate reference systems. Any ideas?
[image]

Comment: How does your data compare to a basemap? Just off hand, I'd suspect that the data isn't projected in the units that are being reported. I had issues with Smallworld (via FME) doing this; it would report meters but it was actually millimeters!

Comment: Are you working in layout view?  My first reaction is that the active data frame is lacking a coordinate system.  Perhaps when the layers were added the first one in lacked a projection definition? Arcmap will use the coordinate system of the active data frame when adding a scale bar, or of the active data frame when you are using the measure tool.  If you are in layout view it is easy to have the "wrong" data frame active; I've done it often.

Comment: Thank you for your comments guys you were right in that I think it was a Project/CRS issue. I overcame it using the methodology posted below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I think happened here was that although the dataframe and all layers were saying they were in the correct Project Coordinate System, they actually weren't registered to one at all. I over came this by first defining the coordinate systems for all the layers to OSGB36 and then projecting them to BNG (which is based on Tranverse Mecator). The map looks different now but I'm assuming thats because it was unprojected before. Scale and Measurements are now working!

[image: Working distance measurements after redefine each layers CRS and projecting them]